# Write the contents of the variable to a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

How can I save the contents of the variable `sum` in this operation?

```
$ seq 1 5 | awk '{sum+=$1} end {print sum; echo "$sum" > test_file}'
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're confusing BASH syntax and Awk. Awk is a programming language, and it has very different syntax from BASH.

```
$ seq 1 5 | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
15
```

You want to capture that `15` into a file:

```
$ seq 1 5 | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' > test_file
```

That is using the *shell's* redirection. The `>` appears outside of the Awk program where the shell has control, and redirects standard out into the file `test_file`.

You can also redirect inside of Awk, but this is *Awk's* redirection. However, it uses the same syntax as BASH:

```
$ seq 1 5 | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum > "test_file" }'
```

Note that the file name has to be quoted, or Awk will assume that `test_file` is a variable, and you'll get some error about redirecting to a null file name.

Answer (score 2):

To write your output into a file, you have to redirect to `"test_file"` like this:

```
$ seq 5 | awk '{sum+=$1} END{print sum > "test_file"}'
$ cat test_file
15
```

Your version was not working because you were not quoting `test_file`, so for `awk` it was considered a variable. And as you have not defined it beforehand, awk couldn't redirect properly. [David W's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20703571/1983854) explains it pretty well.

Note also that `seq 5` is equivalent to `seq 1 5`.

In case you want to save the result into a variable, you can use the `var=$(command)` syntax:

```
$ sum=$(seq 5 | awk '{sum+=$1} END{print sum}')
$ echo $sum
15
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo` won't work in the awk command. Try this:

```
seq 1 5 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum > "test_file"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `awk` for this.  You can say:

```
$ seq 5 | paste -sd+ | bc > test_file
$ cat test_file
15
```

Comment: Then you need `bc` installed.  On `ubuntu` you have `awk` but not `bc` as default.

Answer (score 0):

This question is tagged with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) so here is a pure bash solution:

```
for ((i=1; i<=5; i++)); do ((sum+=i)); done; echo "$sum" > 'test_file'
```

Or this one:

```
for i in {1..5}; do ((sum+=i)); done; echo "$sum" > 'test_file'
```

Answer (score -2):

http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/add_decs.sed

```
#! /bin/sed -f

# This is an alternative approach to summing numbers,
# which works a digit at a time and hence has unlimited
# precision.  This time it is done with lookup tables,
# and uses only 10 commands.

G
s/\n/-/
s/$/-/
s/$/;9aaaaaaaaa98aaaaaaaa87aaaaaaa76aaaaaa65aaaaa54aaaa43aaa32aa21a100/

:loop
/^--[^a]/!{
  # Convert next digit from both terms into analog form
  # and put the two groups next to each other
  s/^\([0-9a]*\)\([0-9]\)-\([^-]*\)-\(.*;.*\2\(a*\)\2.*\)/\1-\3-\5\4/
  s/^\([^-]*\)-\([0-9a]*\)\([0-9]\)-\(.*;.*\3\(a*\)\3.*\)/\1-\2-\5\4/

  # Back to decimal, but keeping the carry in analog form
  # \2 matches an `a' if there are at least ten a's, else nothing
  #
  #    1-------------           3-    4----------------------
  #               2                               5----
  s/-\(aaaaaaaaa\(a\)\)\{0,1\}\(a*\)\([0-9b]*;.*\([0-9]\)\3\5\)/-\2\5\4/
  b loop
}
s/^--\([^;]*\);.*/\1/
h
```

Comment: LOL this must be a joke! You win the award for most ridiculous answer of the year.

Comment: So just saw this comments, when someone vote it down today. It is fine, just give someone the idea which you can do the job in different way. If you are not `Sed` fans, then you will not understand how excite logic in it.